# Matlab Plot 3d axis on a specifi point

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, axis, animated

I want to plot the axis x,y,z as vectors from a specific point.x will be(+-1,0,0) (if the point was the origin)y=(0,+-1,0) and z(0,0,+-1).How can i plot them with different colors in an figure tha already contains some informations

To be specific i have an animated 3D skeleton and i want to have the axes showed in the root of the skeleton.

furthermore if anyone knows how to plot a plane in the same animated 3D skeleton!i want the plane to be as a disc

Thanks in advance for any response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axis off` to turn off matlab's default axis

then use `plot3` to draw the specific lines for the new axes

the `patch` command along with x,y,z coordinates for the contour of the disc will plot the disc plane

Comment: Thank you for your response.I may don't have to use axis off as i only want to draw 3 vectors from a specific point to specific directions every time.I think i only have to use the "line" command.For the patch command i think it is very useful.Thank you again